# Problema con la API de Notificaciones

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en la cual el usuario recibe una notificacion en un momento determinado, para ello estoy usando la API de notificaciones (el objeto Notification que está dentro del objeto window). La cuestion es que el programa funciona perfectamente en firefox, más no en Chromium. La manera en que mando las notificaciones es la siguiente:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(permiso){
       if (permiso === "granted"){
               var notificacion = new Notification("Titulo", {body: "Texto", icon: 'imagen.png'});         
       }
})
```

Con varios `console.log(Notification.permision)` me he dado cuenta de que antes de pedir el permiso (en Chrome) el valor de `Notification.permision` es `default` (cómo esperaba), la cuestion es de que despues de pedir permiso y dar el permiso el valor de `Notification.permision` sigue siendo `default` y no `granted` como yo esperaba.

Comment: Tienes una errata, no es `Notification.permision` sino `Notification.permission`, con dos *eses*. He probado con este código: `Notification.requestPermission(function(permiso){
    console.log(permiso, Notification.permission);
    if (permiso === "granted"){
      var notificacion = new Notification("Titulo", {body: "Texto"});         
    }
  })` y me ha funcionado correctamente, mostrando dos veces "granted"

Comment: Si has puesto `console.log(Notification.permission)` fuera del callback, es normal que te muestre default porque ese código se habrá ejecutando ANTES que el callback

Answer (score 3):

Según la documentación, estás usando la versión anterior de la función (y es obsoleta ahora).

Usando la nueva sintaxis:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permiso){
       if (permiso === "granted"){
               var notificacion = new Notification("Titulo", {body: "Texto", icon: 'imagen.png'});         
       }
})
```

---

Puedes encontrar la [documentación aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission)

Comment: Aunque esté marcada como obsoleta (*deprecated*), sigue siendo válida